# How to create credentials for Jupyterhub?

Tags: bluedata, bluedata-3.7

I have provisioned a **Spark 2.3.1 notebooks & Jupyterhub with SSL & centos7x** cluster on BlueData.

When I access the Jupyerhub service, I am prompted for a username and password:

[image: Credentials for Jupyterhub]

My BlueData Tenant:

- is NOT configured for LDAP/AD
- has **Cluster Superuser Privilege** set to **Site Admin and Tenant Member/Admin**

How can I generate a static username/password credentials for accessing Jupyterhub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First login to the tenant and then navigate to the clusters screen.

Click the link to download the Tenant KeyPair:

[image]

Now, click on the link for the cluster (in my example this is 'test'):

[image]

You can retrieve the jupyterhub ssh hostname and port.  Remember to change the hostname to the gateway hostname.  You can now ssh into the cluster:

```sh
ssh bluedata@your_gw_host -p your_port -i /downloaded/tenant/keypair.pem
```

You can add a user as follows:

```sh
sudo useradd your_username

# set the password for your_username
sudo passwd your_username
```

You can now login to Jupyterhub with those credentials.

Comment: Also see: https://bluedata.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/219860007-Credentials-for-Commonly-Used-Applications-Virtualized-in-BlueData